# Getting the title to show up when map loads with mkmap

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, mapkit

I am able to get a map to show up and a pin to drop where I want in my iphone app project, but I want the title and subtitle to appear when the view loads.  Here is the code I'm using.  I thought putting in
[mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];

would work, but it doesn't.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: 32.02008, longitude: -108.479707};

```
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];


MapController *annotation = [[MapController alloc]  initWithCoordinate:coord];
annotation.currentPoint = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
annotation.mTitle = @"MyTitle";
annotation.mSubTitle = @"My Address";
[mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
[annotation release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling selectAnnotation before it's added to the map won't work and even putting it after the addAnnotation line will not work because the annotation view hasn't been drawn on the map yet.

You'll need to use the didAddAnnotationViews delegate method which is called when annotations are ready to manipulate:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    id<MKAnnotation> myAnnotation = [mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0];
    [mapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];
}
```

The example just assumes you have one annotation and gets it from the mapView's annotations array.  You could also hold a reference to your annotation with an ivar.

Make sure you have set the mapView's delegate property otherwise the method won't be called.

Comment: Thanks..I'm getting this error "local declaration of mapView hides instance variable"  any idea of what that is referring to?  Again, I really appreciate you help on this.

Comment: It's not really going to stop it from working--it's just warning you about a possible name conflict/confusion.  You can change the name of the mapView parameter in the method to something else to make the warning go away.

Comment: Or--probably better option is to change the name of your mapView class variable from mapView to something like myMapView because all the map view's delegate methods by default use "mapView".

Comment: Hmm..I changed this as you suggested, the error went away but it still doesn't show that title...maybe I'm not setting the myMapView delegate property, but could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: First do this test: in the didAddAnnotationViews method, add this as the first line: `NSLog(@"in didAddAnnotationViews");`.  When you run the app, does the annotation pin appear and does "in didAddAnnotationViews" appear in the debug console?

Comment: After you add myMapView as a subview of self.view, you can set the delegate like this: `myMapView.delegate = self;`.  In the view controller's .h file, set the @interface like this: `@interface YourViewControllerNameHere : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>`.